# Why does cookie get lost when I close my Android application?

Tags: android, cookies

I'm developing an Android app and I'm kind of new to this. What I'm currently trying to do is to maintain a user logged in. To login I have to make a request to an API and send the user email and password, that returns a JSONObject which I manage just fine. I have a **CookieStore** variable to get the cookies and store them into my **SharedPreferences**.

I just realised my **cookies get lost** if I close the application and I need to keep making requests to the API even if the app gets resumed, because the user has already logged in. I tried to "restore" the cookies in the onResume() method of one of my activities but that doesn't work the way I want it to. If I try to get the cookies using CookieStore.getCookies() after I resume my app that list is **null**.

I've been told I can use loopj's `AsynHttpClient` and manage my cookies with `PersistentCookieStore` but wouldn't that get me to the same problem? I'd be losing the value of the PersistentCookieStore instance every time I resume my app, right?

so my question is:

**How can I restore the cookies in order to keep them persistent and make me able to keep making requests to the API?**

Hope anyone can help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: storing it using sharedpreferences should work. You can retrieve it when you want to.

Comment: Yeah, but it doesn't. Thing is if I close the app and try to make a new request to the API I don't have any way to tell the API I'm the same user because I lost the cookies. Should I restore them from shared preferences in the exact moment when making the request? What information do I need of the cookie? name, value, domain, path and version?

Comment: sharepreferences will work . retrive the cookie and send the same to the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

Option 1 - If using SharedPreferences and HttpUrlConnection: you need to manually retrieve the cookie from the SharedPreferences and add the cookie to each request when using HttpUrlConnection.

Option 2 - If using loopj AsyncHttpClient: According to the loopj documentation, you must create an instance of PersistentCookieStore and add it to your AsyncHttpClient every time your app is restarted, like so

```
AsyncHttpClient myClient = new AsyncHttpClient();
PersistentCookieStore myCookieStore = new PersistentCookieStore(this);
myClient.setCookieStore(myCookieStore);
```

where 'this' is a Context.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using loopj AsyncHttpClient and it works just fine :)

Answer (score 0):

How do you store/restore your cookies to/from the SharedPreferences? Can you share some code?
Also can you try debugging it and tell us what's wrong with it? Does it not get stored to the SharedPreferences? Does it fail to restore them?

Before storing/restoring the CookieStore to the SharedPreferences, you would need to create a Serializable object with it first, such as an `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>`

Something like:

```
public static void storeCookies(Context context, CookieStore cookieStore) {
  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String> cookies = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>();
  for (Cookie cookie : cookieStore.getCookies()) {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("name", cookie.getName());
    map.put("path", cookie.getPath());
    map.put("domain", cookie.getDomain());
    map.put("expiry_date", cookie.getExpiryDate());
    map.put("ports", cookie.getPorts());
    map.put("value", cookie.getValue());
    map.put("version", cookie.getVersion());
    ...
    // Add all the fields you want to save
    cookies.add(map);
  }

  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences().edit();
  editor.putSerializable("cookies", cookies).apply();
}

public static void addCookiesToStore(Context context, CookieStore cookieStore) {
  List<Map<String, String>> cookies = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) context.getSharedPreferences().getSerializable("cookies");

  for (Cookie map : cookieStore.getCookies()) {
    Cookie cookie = new BasicClientCookie(map.getName(), map.getValue());
    cookie.setPath(map.get("path));
    ...
    // Add all the fields you want to restore
    cookieStore.add(cookie);
  }
}
```